# How to invert the NSImageNameMenuOnStateTemplate image when making a custom NSMenuItem view?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsimage, nsmenuitem, nsimageview

I am writing a custom `NSMenuItem` view. I would like to be able to use the system default "on state" menu item image (the image named `NSImageNameMenuOnStateTemplate`) within an `NSImageView` subview of my custom `NSMenuItem` view.

The checkmark image looks fine when the menu item is not selected. When selected, I need to somehow draw the image in white instead of the normal dark gray color. Otherwise, the dark gray checkmark is barely visible against the dark blue selected menu item background:

[image: Screen shot of the dark gray checkmark against the dark blue selected menu item background]

How do I draw the white checkmark image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I can change the checkmark image color by setting the backgroundStyle of the `NSImageCell` associated with the `NSImageView`.  If the menu item is selected, setting the backgroundStyle to `NSBackgroundStyleDark` will produce a white checkmark.  If the menu item is not selected, setting the backgroundStyle to `NSBackgroundStyleLight` will produce the normal dark-gray checkmark:

```
[stateImageView.cell setBackgroundStyle:(isSelected
                                         ? NSBackgroundStyleDark
                                         : NSBackgroundStyleLight)];
```

If the menu item is disabled, I can produce a disabled checkmark appearance by disabling the cell:

```
[stateImageView.cell setEnabled:NO];
```